# How do I store a value that is negative as zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I store a value that is negative as zero on python?

Example:

```
Enter a number:3
Enter a number:4
3 - 4 = 0
```

The answer is actually -1 but because the answer is negative, the answer is stored as ZERO.

Please help!

Comment: "is stored" or "you want it to be stored" as zero? I'm assuming the latter, but had to read your question several times.

Comment: I want it to be stored. lol! ;)

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [max](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) builtin:

```
a = 3
b = 4
total = max(0, a-b) # total == 0
total = max(0, b-a) # total == 1
```

Comment: +1.  But the OP wants the _answer_ [`to be stored`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632085/how-do-i-store-a-value-that-is-negative-as-zero#comment29146700_19632085) :)

Comment: I need to use an if statement.

Comment: eg: if (a or b < 0):
    #store as 0

Comment: @PolliEster Why do you "need" to use an `if` statement? It doesn't seem like a reasonable requirement. Where does it come from? Do you have any other requirements you haven't stated?

Comment: How do I do it? I need a python line to set at 0 if < 0

Comment: `if total < 0: total = 0`

Answer (score 5):

Just use a conditional expression:

```
result = 3 - 4
total = 0 if result < 0 else result
```